# Different Total Types in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to use Tableau's row total function but am running into a challenge.  In the same widget I have Rows 1 - 4 with Numbers.  Row 5 is a percentage.

What I would like to do is have Rows 1 - 4 use a Sum Total and Row 5 use an Average total.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use different total metrics on the same worksheet.

What you can do is to create 2 different worsheets, and bring them side by side on a dashboard. Then use the proper Total metric in each.

But beware on calculation average of percentages, because they might be twisted. Usually weighted average is required to accurately express the "average" of a percentage.

What you can do is to actually calculate the percentage (use a calculated field) via the division of two metrics. That way, when you do Totals you will actually a valid value for the "average" of the percentage.

As an exercise, suppose you have sales (in $) in first row, and # of clients in row 2. Now I create a calculated field called ticket, that is

```
SUM(sales) / sum([# of clients])
```

That way I can add that to a third row, and for each column I'll have the right number of ticket, and if I add a Row Grand Total, I'll get the actual average ticket value (that is total sales / total # clients), because Tableau will sum all sales, sum all # clients and them perform the calculation (the division)

Comment: That was my understanding as well unfortunately.  I was hoping I was missing something.

Comment: But I strongly recommend the "calculate percentage" anyway.